# How to horizontally center UITextView content in iOS, but not using Align Center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitextview

I want to achieve something very specific. It is hard to describe in words so here are some mockups..

Current stage: I have a UITextView which has autolayout constraints set to be as wide as the parent container. 
[image: Left aligned text]

What I want to achieve: I would like to horizontally center the contents in the UITextView, so that they appear in center but are still left aligned
[image: Content centered but left aligned text]

Most solutions rely on TextAlignCenter option to center the text horizontally, however this is not something that I want as it will appear as such instead:
[image: Centered aligned text]

Any way to achieve this?

I've tried the below:

1. textview.sizeToFit() seems to adjust the height but not the width
2. textview.contentOffset does not seem to work
3. Removing the constraints in autolayout and use Editor > Fix all in scope seems to work on UIButtons but not UITextView..

The reason I want to do this is although it is not noticable on iPhones, on iPads if the text are short they appear all the way to the left, which is very far from my other interactable buttons in my app.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are probably using Swift, but that's fine, here's the code for Objective-C, just convert it.

```
UITextView * _descriptionText = [UITextView new];
[_descriptionText setDelegate:self];
[_descriptionText setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor];
[_descriptionText setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
[_descriptionText setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[_descriptionText setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
```

then, add this textview to a UIView

```
[sss addSubview:_descriptionText];
```

Here's the code for the UIView:

```
UIView * sss = [UIView new];
[sss setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
[self addSubview:sss];
```

Add constraints to the UIView to center the UITextView and to constrain it's bounds by a certain Width on the left and right sides:

```
[sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sss attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:SOME_HEIGHT_NUMBER_YOU_CHOOSE]];

[sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sss attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:SOME_RIGHT_MARGIN_NUMBER_YOU_CHOOSE]];

[sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sss attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0f constant:SOME_LEFT_MARGIN_NUMBER_YOU_CHOOSE]];
```

or choose a width for the UITextView like this with a CenterX constraint:

```
[sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:SOME_WIDTH_NUMBER_YOU_CHOOSE]];

[sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sss attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];
```

And finally, add a CenterY constraint:

```
[sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sss attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];
```

Lastly, constrain the UIView "sss" to it's super view "self" or whatever it's superview is:

```
NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sss);
NSDictionary *  metrics = @{@"bh" : @30, @"bsh" : @40, ... etc, etc,};

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[sss]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-bh-[sss]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

and then, profit!

Formatted code with subclass UIView
ExampleView.m

```
@implementation ExampleView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        UIView * sss = [UIView new];
        [sss setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
        [self addSubview:sss];

        UITextView * _descriptionText = [UITextView new];
        [_descriptionText setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [_descriptionText setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
        [_descriptionText setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [_descriptionText setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [sss addSubview:_descriptionText];

        //do these three constraints
        [sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sss attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:SOME_HEIGHT_NUMBER_YOU_CHOOSE]];

        [sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sss attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:SOME_RIGHT_MARGIN_NUMBER_YOU_CHOOSE]];

        [sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sss attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0f constant:SOME_LEFT_MARGIN_NUMBER_YOU_CHOOSE]];

        //or do these three constraints, but don't do all 6 constraints between these three and the three above

        [sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:SOME_WIDTH_NUMBER_YOU_CHOOSE]];

        [sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sss attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];

        [sss addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_descriptionText attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:sss attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sss);
        NSDictionary *  metrics = @{@"bh" : @30, @"bsh" : @40};

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[sss]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-bh-[sss]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
// this: V:|-bh-[sss] SHOULD WORK, BUT IT MIGHT REQUIRE YOU TO DO THIS: V:|-bh-[sss(HEIGHT_OF_THE_TEXT_VIEW_THAT_YOU_CHOOSE)]
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

ExampleView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface NSHMessagesView : UIView

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, however seems like the UITextView needs to know its width before runtime? For the example I use I wouldn't know what's the width of the longest line before runtime as it depends on user input.

Comment: Yeh, you should set it to something, that's for sure, but you can set that in the constraints where I wrote this sort of thing: SOME_LEFT_MARGIN_NUMBER_YOU_CHOOSE just change everything like this that you see and then select the top three constraints or the three below those constraints and you win

Answer (score 0):

I think you can subclass UITextView or set contentInset. beacause it's subclass scrollView, so i guess set contentInset can achevie the goal.

Comment: contentInset makes it horizontally scrollable, which I want to avoid.